# how to make Table as below picture for resume?

Tags: tables

[image][image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document} 

\begin{longtable}{p{0.25\textwidth}|p{0.7\textwidth}}

\toprule
{\textbf{CIVIL ENGINEERING}} & {$\bullet$ Environmental Engineering and Science} \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space{$\bullet$ Hydrology and Water Management}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space{$\bullet$ Fluid Mechanics \& Hydraulic Machines}\space\space{$\bullet$ Water Resource Engineering}
\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space
{Groundwater Management}
Introduction to Climate change
\\\midrule
\textbf{Other} & {Strength of materials
theory of structures
surveying
geology
construction management}
\\\bottomrule[![this is how i'm getting ][2]][2]

\end{document}
```

**i've used the code but unable to get it to the following picture**

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The text in the image has little to see with the text in your code. What should be preceded by a bullet, exactly?

Comment: actually i made the picture from word and the text in code was what i'm trying roughly.

Comment: Don't use rules from the `booktabs` package in combination with vertical lines.

Comment: Yes, but what requires a bullet really in your code? Or do you mean what you're aiming at is indeed what is in the image?

Comment: thank you Bernard, i've attached the picture which i'm  getting with the code and when i use \item it is taking the default one (other than bullet) so i mentioned the bullet

Answer (score 1):

Probably the following two example help you:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitem]{wide=0pt, nosep, leftmargin= * ,label=\textbullet,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-1\baselineskip}}


\begin{document} 

\begin{longtable}{p{0.25\textwidth}p{0.7\textwidth}}
\toprule
\bfseries CIVIL \newline ENGINEERING & \begin{tabitem} 
                                         \item Environmental Engineering and Science
                                         \item Hydrology and Water Management
                                         \item Register context 
                                         \item Interface List 
                                         \item Capability List 
                                         \item Protocol List
                                         \item Representation List 
                                       \end{tabitem} \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{p{0.25\textwidth}*{2}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule
\bfseries CIVIL \newline ENGINEERING 
    & \begin{tabitem} 
          \item Environmental Engineering and Science
          \item Hydrology and Water Management
          \item Register context 
          \item Interface List 
      \end{tabitem}
    & \begin{tabitem}
          \item Capability List 
          \item Protocol List
          \item Representation List 
      \end{tabitem} \\
\bottomrule
\end{xltabular}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose this layout:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, nosep, label=$\bullet$, before=\vspace*{-\baselineskip},after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}l*{2}{>{\compress\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textbf{CIVIL ENGINEERING}} \\[0.5ex]
&
 \begin{tabitemize}
\item Environmental Engineering and Science
\item Hydrology and Water Management
\item Fluid Mechanics \& Hydraulic Machines
\end{tabitemize}
 &
 \begin{tabitemize}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, nosep, before=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}, after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}]
\item Water Resource Engineering
\item Groundwater Management
\item Introduction to Climate change
\end{tabitemize}
\\
\midrule
\textbf{OTHER} \\[0.5ex]make &
 \begin{tabitemize}
 \item Strength of materials
\item theory of structures
\item surveying geology
\item construction management
\end{tabitemize}
\\
\bottomrule
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]